# Connecting Java to MySQL through that requires proxy, username and password

Tags: java, mysql, proxy, connection

I am working on a desktop application that connects to a MySQL database in a godaddy.com server.

Everything is working fine, except when working from a network that requires a proxy, username and a password

Do I need to set the proxy from the code? How?
Or is there away around?

Here is my database connection code:

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://XXXXX.db.XXXXX.hostedresource.com/";
dbName = "XXXXXX";
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
unicode = "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
try{
    Class.forName(driver);
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName+unicode, "XXXXX", "XXXXX");
}catch (Exception e) {javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);}
```

Comment: Try talking to the sysadmin to open up non-HTTP access if blocked...

Comment: What sort of proxy is it?  In general, proxies are set up to proxy just HTTP connections, and won't allow other arbitrary TCP connections through.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to make sure the java runtime is able to access the Internet through your proxy, and to do that see [how to setup proxy for java](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/proxy_setup.xml).

You should also set up the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable for your shell. Syntax is

`HTTP_PROXY = http://username@password:proxy.server.com:8080/`

However, note that (at least for Windows), if you add the above to your system variables, they will only take effect on the next reboot and you need admin rights to modify system variables. You can add it to your user variables and they will take effect on next login (or next invocation of the command prompt).

Comment: That would proxy HTTP generally, not any TCP connection.

Comment: Yes, but typically for NTLM proxies that is sufficient.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid How to set the HTTP_PROXY. I mean what is the full command that I should use in Command Line prompt?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I used the line you post HTTP_PROXY = http.... but its not recognized as a command in cmd

Answer (score 0):

HTTP proxies will not forward your JDBC (in this case MySQL) at all.

You can setup HTTPS CONNECT proxy with SSH tunneling, but this is different story.

Comment: For Windows environments and NTLM, this authentication on the HTTP proxy is required for _any_ access. We have the same issue at work.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid : OP tries to connect to Mysql DB via proxy.No NTLM auth.